# How to move files from on-prem NAS to AWS S3 when file arrives on NAS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nas

I have a requirement where we need to move files from on-prem NAS storage to AWS S3.
Files keep coming on NAS storage when it arrives we have notification set up in AWS and then we need to pull files from AWS to S3.

1. Can I access NAS storage and pull files from AWS to S3?
2. Does it require any additional configuration or simple EC2 or Lambda function can work based on size of the file?
3. How about NAS --> SFTP --> S3 using AWS Transfer family solution.
4. Is there any better way to move files from NAS to S3?

We want to avoid writing code as much as we can.

Comment: You're looking for a push solution here, not a pull solution. DataSync most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [AWS Datasync](https://aws.amazon.com/datasync/).
It is a data transfer service of AWS that allow to copy data to and from AWS storage services over the Internet or over AWS Direct Connect (protocols NFS, SMB).

You don't need `EC2` or `AWS lambda`. You have to install an agent that will read from a source location, and sync your data to `S3`. The agent is deployed on-premise. Please find the supported Hypervisor here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/agent-requirements.html and the deployment guide here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/deploy-agents.html

Comment: I think you mixed your URL. Datasync is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/datasync/).

Comment: Thanks @Mornor, I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer ...So this agent will be deployed on prem server ?

Comment: @SUDARSHAN, yes the agent is deployed on-premise. Please find the supported Hypervisor here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/agent-requirements.html and the deployment guide here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/deploy-agents.html

Comment: @Sudarshankumar , How you manged to sync files data arrives daily once done with data sync operations ?